# Wp All Import - Exclude product id from title

Tags: php, wpallimport

I want to import products by XML but the products has ids at the and of the titles,

here is a short title for example: “Levis bootcut jean 5450313”,

the id is “5450313”,

how can i Exclude product ids and import a clear title: “Levis bootcut jean”,

i have an example function but i don't know how to modify for my case:

```
function my_fix_title( $title ) {
$title = explode( ' ', $title );
array_pop( $title );
return implode( ' ', $title ); }
```

Wp All Import call the function like this: [my_fix_title({product_name[1]})]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

<strike>array_pop delete the last element of the array and return it. So we can simply catch the return value from array_pop and send it back to the caller function. Please try following</strike>

```
function my_fix_title( $title ) {
$title = explode( ' ', $title );
$id = array_pop( $title );
return $id; 
}
```

**UPDATES**:
Since the OP had an issue with the cache and the method he has worked fine, this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: I tried but it returned a double id: Levis bootcut jean 5450313 5450313

Comment: it shouldn't, here is the playground link https://tehplayground.com/Sn6zraJornLTaMRi

Comment: the playground link returned only the id: 5450313

Comment: the point is do not return the id, only the title "Levis bootcut jean"

Comment: oh sorry, I read it vice versa. Then the function you have is already good. https://tehplayground.com/xiLRcZ8Xunp9YTyi

Comment: yes it works, the browser cache was the issue, i tried with another browser, so the function i have is the right solution, thanks for your help, sorry if you wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Could also use `preg_replace` too:

```
$title1 = 'some product 24556';
$title2 = 'another product 56789';

function my_fix_title( $title ) {
    $fixedTitle = preg_replace('/[ ]\d+$/', '', $title);
    return $fixedTitle;
}

echo my_fix_title($title1);
echo '<br>';
echo my_fix_title($title2);
```

Output:

```
some product
another product
```

Example [fiddle](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf72ff5df2fbed40b5121adc07651afd5486b62f)

The `'/[ ]\d+$/'` explanation:

```
/   // Start pattern
[ ] // A space
\d+ // One or more digits
 $  // At the end of the string
/   // End pattern
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work in wpallimport, it returned the same title: Levis bootcut jean 5450313

Comment: thanks for the regex explanation my friend. It's important for me. Regards.